# BigQuery SPLIT with multiple delimiters

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to make a left split URIs when a character like "?" or "#" appears.

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN URI LIKE '%?%' THEN FIRST(SPLIT(URI, "?"))
WHEN URI LIKE '%#%' THEN FIRST(SPLIT(URI, "#"))
END WITHIN RECORD AS URI_FILTER
FROM (SELECT "/A/A1/AA2/205.html#jfsalf" AS URI)
```

Output must be: `/A/A1/AA2/205.html`

Another URI to test:

```
/A/A1/AA2/205.html?pRef=209888
```

*Error: Scope applied without an aggregation function*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [regular expression](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#regularexpressionfunctions) better fit for this

```sql
SELECT 
  URI, REGEXP_EXTRACT(URI, r'(.*?)[?#]')
FROM 
  (SELECT "/A/A1/AA2/205.html#jfsalf" AS URI),
  (SELECT "/A/A1/AA2/205.html?pRef=209888" as URI)
```

Answer (score 4):

The SPLIT function returns the data in ARRAY format (nested cells) which can be quite useful for some purposes.

If you desire this format, the alternative is to use the REPLACE operation to convert the various keys (#, %, etc) to a single key you can use in SPLIT.

In the below code, we convert # to ? and then split on ?.

SPLIT(  REPLACE( URI, "#", "?" ), "?" )

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_EXTRACT`. If it's possible that the URI doesn't have a `#` or `?`, you can use a regular expression that accounts for that case:

```
#standardSQL
WITH T AS (
  SELECT '/A/A1/AA2/205.html#jfsalf' AS path UNION ALL
  SELECT '/A/A1/AA2/205.html?pRef=209888' AS path UNION ALL
  SELECT '/A/A1/AA2/205.html' AS path
)
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, r'([^#?]+)') AS left_path
FROM T;
```